# No results for in app purchase product query with Flutter app on Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, flutter-in-app-purchase

UPDATE: Works now. I don't know why I did not change anything. Maybe Google needs more time these days...

I am struggling to query products for my android app. The app is created with Flutter and uses the official [In App Purchase Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase). I assume it is a configuration problem on Google Play Store. In the past, I succeeded in writing apps that can access in-app products with this setup.

Query:

```
var productsResponse = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
    .queryProductDetails({_registrationId, _subscriptionId});
```

Result:

[image]

App configuration on Google Play:

- App is published in the internal test track
- App ID on Google Play is identical to the entry in `build.gradle`
- `Billing` capability was added
- Two products configured (subscription and consumable), the IDs are identical to the ones I use in the code
- Test track has two invited users (developer account and my personal account), the mail addresses are correct

Some remarks:

- `isAvailable()` returns true and is called before the query
- When using the string ´android.test.purchased´ in the query, I get results
- My phone runs with my personal account which is NOT the developer/Google Play account, but my account is on the test tracklist
- EDIT: I changed to the developer account on my phone, but the same result
- I am not using the published APK to test, I am testing with the DEBUG version on my phone
- `flutter clean` and manual app removal from the phone was done several times

Does anyone have any hints for me? It could be something totally stupid I just don't see at the moment.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE: I upgraded the app to the alpha track, sadly results didn't change. It does not seem to be track related.

Comment: Hi xmarshalax, I just wanted to first of all say it does take 24 hours or so for Google to verify the app release on the Alpha track or any track for that matter and I would just like to notify you that you bounty is still active. Please mark it as closed and answered too.

Comment: I had to wait 5 days in the end which was much longer than I expected. Even though the app was available in the different tracks I could not query the in app products. That's why I was worried that I missed something important to configure. And as long as the bounty is active I can't do anything here :)

Comment: Yeah it was quite a similar process for me, but in the end it was the verification problem of the app in the closed track and a typo which cost me 48 hours. Oh, I see the bounty expires tomorrow.

Comment: Why is this taking so long? Isn't it necessary to quickly approve the alpha track on the closed track?

Comment: I also have this issue and have waited about one week but it is still not working.....

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing out that the app ID has to be identical to the one querying the inapp products! I had a debug-flavor with a different application ID defined in the build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind to use the product id of the subscription group, not of the subscription offer.

Here you see what I mean in the subscription settings of the play store console.

[image: Image showing illustrating that there is a product id for a subscription group and a ID for each subscription duration]

Comment: Thankyouuuu, very helpful answer :)