# Flutter in_app_purchase not loading on Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I do use : https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

The following code work perfectly on IOS real device but it cannot connect to Google Play store on Android.

IOS : working perfectly

Android : Stuck on line

```
 final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
```

it load forever
The isAvailable command never end. There is no error returned.

```
Future<void> _purchasePremiumInstallation(DateTime _premiumExpireDt) async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        widget.isLoadingPurchase = true;
      });
      setState(() {
        widget.error = 'good 1';
      });
      //in_app_purchase initialisation
      try {
        if (!kIsWeb) {
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 2';
          });
          String productIdString = '';
          if (Platform.isIOS) productIdString = 'PremiumInstallation_1Y';
          if (Platform.isAndroid) productIdString = 'premiuminstallation_1y';
          print('in_app_payment : ' + productIdString);
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 3';
          });
          final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 4';
          });
          if (!available) {
            print('ERROR in_app_purchase - Cannot connect to the store');
            setState(() {
              widget.isLoadingPurchase = false;
            });
            setState(() {
              widget.error = 'Error cannot connect to the store';
            });
            errorPopUp(
                context, 'ERROR in_app_purchase - Cannot connect to the store');
          }
          //first android then ios
          Set<String> _kIds = <String>{
            productIdString,
          };
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 4';
          });
          final ProductDetailsResponse response =
              await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 5';
          });
          if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
            print('Error in_app_purchase item id not found');
            setState(() {
              widget.isLoadingPurchase = false;
            });
            setState(() {
              widget.error = 'Error item not found';
            });
            errorPopUp(context, 'Error in_app_purchase item id not found');
          }
          List<ProductDetails> products = response.productDetails;
          print('in_app_purchase item found' + products.toString());
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 6';
          });
          final ProductDetails productDetails =
              products.first; // Saved earlier from queryProductDetails().
          print('in_app_purchase product detail we are gonna buy is :' +
              productDetails.id);
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 7';
          });
          final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
              PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
          InAppPurchase.instance
              .buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam, autoConsume: true);
          print('in_app_purchase completed');
          setState(() {
            widget.error = 'good 8';
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error catched for in_app_purchase : ' + e.toString());
        setState(() {
          widget.isLoadingPurchase = false;
        });
        setState(() {
          widget.error = e.toString();
        });
        errorPopUp(context, e.toString());
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      errorPopUp(context, err).show();
      setState(() {
        widget.error = err.toString();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      errorPopUp(context, err).show();
      setState(() {
        widget.error = err.toString();
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      widget.isLoadingPurchase = false;
    });
  }
```

also i have that line on main - app init

```
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
        InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases();
      }
```

Comment: InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable() is a Future callback. Could you try adding catchError and onError on isAvailable to debugPrint any error thrown from the Future callback? I'm unable to replicate the same issue on InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable() locally

Comment: The line InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable() doesn't throw any error. It run forever, no timeout or anything. That's pretty weird i think i am the only one with that problem on the web. It's only happening on Android. Work perfectly fine on ios

Comment: This answer might help you, check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/56643449/11352456

Comment: did you solve this issue? right now i am facing same issue.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma no i finally used another plugin what about you

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Removing the billing client implementation from the app-level build.gradle solved it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135939/flutter-in-app-purchase-stuck-at-queryproductdetails-method/70589769#70589769) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the product ID of the subscription group and not the ID for the subscription duration.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74733040/5833548