# InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable() returning false

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase

When using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase), the following code always returns false for `isAvailable`:

```
final isAvailable = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
```

This is called in a `GestureDectector` onTap callback.

I am trying to connect to the Play store. The code is running on the Android Emulator. I am using in_app_purchase version 3.0.6.

I don't have billing client implementation in app-level build.gradle, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590035/2233706). The only config-level setting I have related to in_app_purchase is the dependency in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Have you tried it in Real Device?

Comment: Yes, it works on a real device. We can simulate for iOS. It'd be nice if this was possible on Android simulator.

Comment: You can try by logging in your google account in simulator

Comment: I did login to the same Google account I setup for the closed testing.

Comment: newest version 3.1.1; sttill doesn't work on Android Emulator, even after logging in with google tester account.